# Rails multiple drop down make it stick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, drop-down-menu

I have created dropdown language selection list, however I would like to make it stick when user edits. I know that it can be done with the second argument of `select_tag` but could not do it.

I have a user model and associated language model;

```
<%= f.label :language, "Spoken Languages" %>
    <br>

    <%= select_tag("user[language_ids][]", options_for_select(Language.all.collect { |ff| [ff.name, ff.id] }, @user.languages.all.collect { |kk| [kk.name, kk.id] }), 
                   {:multiple=>true, :class => "language_select form-control"}) %>
```

EDIT:

Here how it looks like, even though spoken languages are set before;

[image]

But it should look like with the pre selected languages (comes from database);

[image]

I used ***Select2*** to create the dropdown list.

Comment: What do you mean by make it stick?

Comment: @Nathan; when user tries to edit, he/she should be able to see selected data

Comment: Still unclear. I think you'll need to describe your problem in a better way if you don't want your question to be closed.

Comment: @Nathan is it clear now?

Comment: This helps, but it seems like you're using a JS library for that type of multi-select field. Which library?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, it is select2

Comment: I would first make sure that: `@user.languages` gives you what you need. You can also remove the `all` on this, as it's implied. If you're getting the data you expect, try changing this part to: `@user.languages.collect { |kk| kk.id }`

Comment: Ok, @Nathan thank you it worked, I have put kk.name in a wrong way. If you can write it as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Excellent! Glad that helped ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this part to: `@user.languages.collect { |kk| kk.id }`